# Extract multiple class into pandas dataframe using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get the following pandas dataframe:

[image: Desired output]

Here is all what I tried, did tried to pass the class but does provide all the content and not the separate as I'm looking into to get. I'm new to bs4.

```
html_doc = """
<div class="schoolinfo" data-attr-lat="33.7527" data-attr-lon="-84.3867" id="1396">
      <div class="schoolheader">
       <h3 class="schoolname">
        Georgia State University
       </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="schooldetails">
       <div class="schoollocation">
        <div class="citystate">
         Atlanta, Georgia
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="programs">
        <div class="schoolprogram">
         <h4>
          <a href="http://cs.gsu.edu/graduate/doctor-philosophy/ph-d-bioinformatics-concentration-degree-requirements/" target="_blank">
           Ph.D. in Computer Science - Bioinformatics Concentration
          </a>
         </h4>
         <div class="cost-curric">
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default detailbutton" href="http://cs.gsu.edu/graduate/doctor-philosophy/ph-d-admission-requirements/" target="_blank">
           HOW TO APPLY
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default detailbutton" href="https://catalog.gsu.edu/graduate20152016/computer-science/" target="_blank">
           CURRICULUM
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default detailbutton" href="http://sfs.gsu.edu/tuition-fees/what-it-costs/tuition-and-fees/" target="_blank">
           COST
          </a>
         </div>
         <div class="programdetails">
          <div class="dept">
           <strong>
            OFFERED BY:
           </strong>
           Department of Computer Science
          </div>
          <div class="dept">
           <strong>
            DELIVERY:
           </strong>
           Campus
          </div>
          <div class="dept">
           <strong>
            LENGTH:
           </strong>
           48 Credits
          </div>
          <div class="dept">
           <strong>
            PRE-REQUISITE TECHNICAL COURSEWORK:
           </strong>
           technical bachelor's degree
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())

for i in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': ["schoolname", "citystate", "schoolprogram","dept"]}):
    print(i)
```

Doesn't provide the desired tags and pass all the html content without any filtering, if I pass only 1 class than I get required tag but not a list of tags ... here is the output of the **find_all** with multiple **"class"**

```
<h3 class="schoolname">
            Georgia State University
           </h3>
<div class="citystate">
             Atlanta, Georgia
            </div>
<div class="schoolprogram">
<h4>
<a href="http://cs.gsu.edu/graduate/doctor-philosophy/ph-d-bioinformatics-concentration-degree-requirements/" target="_blank">
               Ph.D. in Computer Science - Bioinformatics Concentration
              </a>
</h4>
<div class="cost-curric">
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default detailbutton" href="http://cs.gsu.edu/graduate/doctor-philosophy/ph-d-admission-requirements/" target="_blank">
               HOW TO APPLY
              </a>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default detailbutton" href="https://catalog.gsu.edu/graduate20152016/computer-science/" target="_blank">
               CURRICULUM
              </a>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default detailbutton" href="http://sfs.gsu.edu/tuition-fees/what-it-costs/tuition-and-fees/" target="_blank">
               COST
              </a>
</div>
<div class="programdetails">
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                OFFERED BY:
               </strong>
               Department of Computer Science
              </div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                DELIVERY:
               </strong>
               Campus
              </div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                LENGTH:
               </strong>
               48 Credits
              </div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                PRE-REQUISITE TECHNICAL COURSEWORK:
               </strong>
               technical bachelor's degree
              </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                OFFERED BY:
               </strong>
               Department of Computer Science
              </div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                DELIVERY:
               </strong>
               Campus
              </div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                LENGTH:
               </strong>
               48 Credits
              </div>
<div class="dept">
<strong>
                PRE-REQUISITE TECHNICAL COURSEWORK:
               </strong>
               technical bachelor's degree
              </div>
```

Code for multiple:

```
pathP = "http://www.mastersindatascience.org/schools/doctorate/#on-campus" #text for multiple 

response = requests.get(pathP)
response.text[:100] # Access the HTML with the text property
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use `.find_all` with list of attributes here, because for some texts you want to access would be better to have them specifically stored, instead of storing all of them, in order of appearance. So get each of them to their specific variables:

```
citystate = soup.find('div',{'class':'citystate'}).text.strip()
dept = soup.find('div',{'class':'dept'}).text.strip()
dept = dept[dept.index(':')+1:].strip()
link = soup.find('div',{'class':'schoolprogram'}).a['href']
schoolname = soup.find('h3',{'class':'schoolname'}).text.strip()
schoolprogram = soup.find('div',{'class':'schoolprogram'}).a.text.strip()
```

About the line `dept = dept[dept.index(':')+1:].strip()`, it is making the `dept` be what you really want, instead of beginning with `"OFFERED BY:"`. Also, calling `.strip()` in all of them to get rid of the numerous `\n`.

Now you can create your `DataFrame` using pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[citystate, dept, link, schoolname, schoolprogram]],
                  columns = ['citystate', 'dept', 'link', 'schoolname', 'schoolprogram'])
```

---

```
>>> print(df.to_string())
          citystate                            dept                                               link                schoolname                                      schoolprogram
0  Atlanta, Georgia  Department of Computer Science  http://cs.gsu.edu/graduate/doctor-philosophy/p...  Georgia State University  Ph.D. in Computer Science - Bioinformatics Con...
```

---

If you are dealing with lots of these, you should just replace all the `.find` with `.findAll` and then get their texts in a list comprehension, for `schoolprogram` we would have:

```
schoolprogram = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'schoolprogram'})]
```

Comment: for multiple ones:  dept = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'dept'})] #how works the strip please ?
dept = dept[dept.index(':')+1:].strip() . #Thank you .  ValueError: ':' is not in list

Comment: first  `dept = [x.text() for x in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'dept'})]` and then 
`dept = [x[x.index(':')+1:].strip() for x in dept]` --- If my answer is helpful, please remember to [accept/upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer, it's an overall good for the community.

Comment: dept = [x[x.index(':')+1:].strip() for x in dept] #does only extract position 1 element from the list, need to find a way to extract from: OFFERED BY: Computer Science Department
and DELIVERY: Online

Comment: looking onto regex now to see if can get a way to do it

Comment: @Vksu don't use regex for html, bs4 can do what you want here, to find the other you can search for the occurence of "DELIVERY" in some `dept` class, then select this one.